# WordPress Sumo Plugin not showing all images on clicking pinterest icon

Tags: plugins, social-sharing

I am using SUMOMME WordPress Plugin for social sharing on WordPress Site.
This is the site: https://www.teachworkoutlove.com/

I am facing below issue when i share post with pinterest.

General working of the plugin is like when i click on pinterest, sumome plugin will detect all the images in a post and show in a popup box and then we need to select the specific image to share.

BUT FOR SOME POST, PINTEREST DOES NOT DETECT ALL THE IMAGES 
SEE FOR EXAMPLE: https://www.teachworkoutlove.com/7-great-gifts-for-your-groom-after-marriage/

There are nearly 6 images in a post content, but when i click on pinterest, it show only few images in a popup that provide selection to share the images to pinterest.

I have checked the console, but there does not exists any error.

Is there any setting i am missing on specific posts?

Can any one help me out with what causing this to happen ?

Note: This is plugin , so i cannot share any code on how plugin work. So don't comment that "sHARE YOUR CODE". Hope developer will understand.

Comment: Third party plugin questions are considered off topic here. Have you tried reaching their official support, ie the wordpress.org forums?

Comment: Yes. I have already raised a question over there. See here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-sumo-plugin-not-showing-all-images-on-clicking-pinterest-icon/,  but no response so hoping some response from stackoverflow community